# Hibernate memory leak -BoundedConcurrentHashMap

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, memory-leaks, spring-transactions

Please help in solving the memory issue in the Spring MVC application

Please find my transaction configurations

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.databaseurl}${jdbc.encoding}" p:user="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"
        p:minPoolSize="${minPoolSize}" p:maxPoolSize="${maxPoolSize}"
        p:checkoutTimeout="${checkoutTimeout}" p:maxIdleTime="${maxIdleTime}"
        p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="${idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />

jdbc:

minPoolSize=15
initalPollSize=25
maxPoolSize=60
#Give up waiting for a connection after this many milliseconds
checkoutTimeout=18000
maxIdleTime=3600
idleConnectionTestPeriod=300
maxStatements=100
numHelperThreads=15
acquireIncrement=10

    <!--session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor">
            </property>

        </bean>

    <!-- transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </bean>



    <!-- transaction interveptor -->

    <bean id="transactionInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
            <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />

        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
            <property name="beanNames">
                <list>
                    <value>*Service</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="interceptorNames">
                <list>
                    <value>exceptionInterceptor</value>
                    <value>transactionInterceptor</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

After the performance  test my memory is not getting released.So when analysed the heap dump got the below error

One instance of "org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x76000b8e8" occupies 73,446,008 (32.66%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x76000b8e8".

org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl @ 0x7624efeb0
 136 49,987,288 34.31% 
\org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache @ 0x7630b1250
 32 47,674,176 32.72% 
.\org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap @ 0x763259a58
 48 47,554,336 32.64% 
..\org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Segment[32] @ 0x7632d1c60
 144 47,554,288 32.64%

### Class Name                                                                                                                                         | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage

org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Segment[32] @ 0x7632d1c60                                                         |          144 |    47,554,288 |     32.64%
|- org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Segment @ 0x76325ac88                                                          |           48 |     1,497,688 |      1.03%
|- org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$Segment @ 0x76325ac58                                                          |           48 |     1,631,272 |      1.12%
|  |- org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap$LIRSHashEntry @ 0x768fd54c0                                                 |           56 |           880 |      0.00%
|  |  |- org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.sql.NativeSQLQuerySpecification @ 0x7671eb8e8                                                              |           32 |            48 |      0.00%
|  |  |  '- org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.sql.NativeSQLQueryReturn[0] @ 0x768ff16d0                                                               |           16 |            16 |      0.00%
|  |  |- org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan @ 0x768ff1640                                                                           |           24 |           520 |      0.00%

### |  |  |- java.lang.String @ 0x768ff1658  SELECT DISTINCT `column` FROM `table` WHERE `column` IN (94316) |           24 |           256 |      0.00%

Please help to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

We observed a query in heap.

from table where statusFlg='Y' and deleteFlg='N' and id="+autoGeneratedId

and when we changed the query to

from table where statusFlg='Y' and deleteFlg='N' and id= :instanceid").setParameter("instanceId,autoGeneratedId)

the session objects are getting garbage collected.

Can some one explain in deail

Comment: in first case, everytime different query is generated and cached. Due to many different queries memory usage keep on increasing based on different values of autoGeneratedId.
in second case, only one paramaterized query is generated, so memory usage remain constant.